# Entity Framework AsNoTracking() Infinite Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, dbcontext, navigation-properties

I have implementation like this:

```
var query = this.DbContext.Set<T>();

if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Any())
{
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperty))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
    }
}

return await query.Where<T>(predicate).ToListAsync();
```

I'd like to make this query `AsNoTracking()` and I'm interested if its important where to call `AsNoTracking()`?

Does it make any difference if I put it here:

```
var query = this.DbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
```

or here:

```
return await query.Where<T>(predicate).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Will both perform query `.AsNoTracking()` same way or not?

Also I'm interested if `.Include()` is also affected by any of these `.AsNoTracking()` or do I have to put additional `.AsNoTracking()` like this:

```
query = query.Include(includeProperty).AsNoTracking();
```

I'm having trouble with `.Include()` because I get infinite recursive navigation properties and when using `Automapper` I get `stackoverflow`, so I'm not quite sure if I'm using `AsNoTracking()` correctly (or `AsNoTracking()` doesn't affect infinite nesting of properties, although I read that somewhere, but only tracks changes in `Context` for further CUD operations?)

I also have these in my Context subclass:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Though my main problem is inifinite navigation property references, I'd really appreciate if someone could also explain correct usage of `AsNoTracking()` from beginning of question (although, for example, it doesn't have anything to do with the problem).

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is all over the place.  What are you asking and what can you eliminate from your question to make it more clear?  Finally, what is the smallest code sample required to reproduce your problem?

Comment: My main concern is if it matters where I put AsNoTracking() on query (of course before executing e.g. calling ToList())?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The error is caused by a reference loop that happens irrespective of tracking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not important where to call `AsNoTracking()`. Basically all it does is sets [ObjectQuery.MergeOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.mergeoption(v=vs.110).aspx) (and some other properties) on internal `ObjectQuery`, so it doesn't matter where to do that until actual query execution.

Yes, all `Include`ed entities will also not be tracked by a context.

No, `LazyLoadingEnabled = false`, `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` and `AsNoTracking()` will **not** solve *all* your infinite recursion problems, especially if you are using includes. Look for how to map such recursive entities with automapper correctly, doing anything on EF side will not help.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed to know!